# How to send Angular JS scope variable as a complete object on ng-click as a parameter to a function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, ng-bind

> *I'm trying to pass a complete repeat object data as a parameter through ng-click function.*

**like :**

```
getImages($index,award)

"{
   "piaKey": 3, "etc": "etc.."
}"
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="award in awards track by $index">
    <span class="col-lg-1 col-md-1">{{$index+1}}.</span>
    <div id="award-{{$index+1}}" class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 mb10 pad0 listViewInner">
        <div class="infoHead">{{award.piaAwardName}}
                    </div>
        <div class="infoAdditional">{{award.piaDescription}} 
                    </div>
        <div class="popViewUploadBtns">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getImages($index,award)" type="button">
                <span class="fa fa-photo"></span>View Photos
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

***attachData*** is undefined

```
$scope.getImages = function(index,attachData){
    $http.get('localhost:8082/wasta/fileRetrieve?referenceKey='+attachData.piaKey+'&referenceType='+attachData.piaType+'&fileType='+attachData.piaFileType).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.attachedPhoto = data;
    })
}
```

If I pass like this **getImages($index,award.piaKey)**, I'm getting the data perfectly like *"3"*, where as **award** i'm not getting the whole data.
here I'm trying to get the

**attachData** 
like : **"{ "piaKey": 3, "etc": "etc.." }"**

Comment: `attachData` in `$scope.getImages` should be `data`. But you should state which is the issue you are having

Comment: the point is I'm not getting the object here, any way its also a point. it is changed.

Comment: attachData is undefined

Comment: Just to confirm is `getImages` on the same controller where you defined `awards`? And are you getting the current index?

Comment: ya everything in the same controller.  if I pass like this getImages($index,award.piaAwardName), I'm getting the data, where as award i'm not getting the whole data.

Answer (score 0):

Change attachData to data

```
   $scope.getImages = function(index,data){
--**change**--------------------------^
        $http.get('localhost:8082/wasta/fileRetrieve?referenceKey='+data.piaKey+'/referenceType='+data.piaType+'/fileType='+data.piaFileType).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.attachedPhoto = data;
        })
    }
```

Demo Link
https://plnkr.co/edit/lMI4bNsuGaETOpw5koSa?p=preview

Comment: the point is I'm not getting the object here, any way its also a point. it is changed.

Comment: attachData is undefined

Comment: Have a look at Plunker demo link